# How can i add, sum, multiply and divide very Big Data Integer in C++

Tags: c++, biginteger

There is a way in java to use BigInteger Class For Big Integer  addition,subtraction, multiplication and division. but i want to do it by c++ without any built in class. can anyone give me the idea??

Comment: Why the bigdata tag?

Comment: Sure, you are dealing with **big** integers, but those can be hold in the memory of your laptop, right?

Comment: You do it one digit/word at a time, or you get a library (or you use a language that supports it better out of the "box.")

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ big number library", since the standard C++ language has no faculties for big number support.

Comment: For the simplest, self-teaching approach, just create a class that stores its value in a `std::string` - one digit per character - and start implementing the maths operators using the same logic you would use doing it with pencil and paper.  Be mindful of the difference between ASCII '0' and numeric 0.  For a more serious approach, use a `std::vector<uint32_t>` or `std::vector<uint64_t>` in combination with `bool` for sign.  If you have a go and get stuck, ***then*** post a specific question.  If you just want a library, seeking recommendations are off-topic for S.O., though Luke's obliged.

Comment: Yeah using string i did. but what about when it exceeds limit of string data?? i want the perfect algorithm like modulus mathmatic procedure. i heared that big integer is implemented by modulus arithmatic. but i don't know the implementation.

Comment: @shawon: strings can grow pretty much as large as your virtual memory (i.e. many billions of digits on any PC).  A binary representation will be 2.56 times more memory efficient, but that's not orders-of-magnitude - not a reason to care for a learning exercise.  Whatever you heard about modulus arithmetic would be more relevant for the `std::vectror<uintN_t>` approach I mentioned, where you'd need to think about more digits carrying or being lost than you're used to doing maths long-hand on paper.  For the string approach though, just forget that and have a go.

Answer (score 2):

For big integer arithmetic in C++, there's no standard library support. But you can use [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).